# Finding items with exact subitems in two lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of students who take courses in a school. My classes look like this:

```
public class Student
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And the `Course` looks like this:

```
public class Course
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find students from both `List A` and `List B` who take the exact same courses.

Say, I have John in `List A` who takes English, Algebra and Chemistry. I want to find all students in `List B` who also take English, Algebra and Chemistry. If a student, say James, in `List B` takes these three courses but an additional course, it would NOT qualify. So the courses they take must match exactly.

And I'll be doing this for every student in `List A`.

I'm not sure how to handle the exact match of courses using `LINQ`. I thought about using `Contains` but I need to make sure **ALL** the courses student from `List A` is taking match the ones student from `List B` is taking.

I'm open to using nested `foreach` but I think `LINQ` could handle it too and possibly perform better.

I'd appreciate some pointers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-8.0): for each student from `listA` we want to get a *group* from `listB` with the same courses:

```
var result = listA
  .GroupJoin(listB,
     a => string.Join(",", a.Courses.Select(course => course.Id).OrderBy(g => g)),
     b => string.Join(",", b.Courses.Select(course => course.Id).OrderBy(g => g)),
    (a, bs) => (student: a, list: bs.ToList()))
  .Where(group => group.list.Count > 0)
  .ToList(); // <- let's have a list
```

For instance, for

```
  Course algebra = new Course() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Algebra" };
  Course geometry = new Course() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Geometry" };
  Course arithmetics = new Course() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Arithmetics" };

  List<Student> listA = new List<Student>() {
    new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "John", Courses = new List<Course>() { algebra, geometry} },
    new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Anna", Courses = new List<Course>() { algebra } }
  };

  List<Student> listB = new List<Student>() {
    new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Jack", Courses = new List<Course>() { algebra, geometry} },
    new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Jill", Courses = new List<Course>() { algebra, geometry}, },
    new Student() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Natasha", Courses = new List<Course>() { algebra, geometry, arithmetics} }
  };
```

If we run the query above and print it as

```
var report = result
  .Select(group => $"{group.student.Name} : {string.Join(", ", group.list.Select(s => s.Name))}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

We'll get

```
John : Jack, Jill
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ikuKG)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<Student, List<Student>> result = listA
    .ToDictionary(
        keySelector: studentA => studentA,
        elementSelector: studentA =>
            listB.Where(studentB =>
                // check that they have same number of courses
                studentA.Courses.Count == studentB.Courses.Count
                // check that all courses are the same
                && studentA.Courses.Select(c => c.Id).Intersect(studentB.Courses.Select(c => c.Id)).Count() == studentA.Courses.Count)
            .ToList());
```

The result is a dictionary where the key is a student from list A and values are students with matching courses from list B.

It's basically checking that the count of courses is the same and also that the intersect between courses has the same count, therefore the courses are all exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
//studentList is the List of Student object
var john = studentList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "John");
var studentLikeJohn = studentList.Where(x => john.Courses.IntersectBy(x.Courses.Select(y => y.Name), y => y.Name).Count() == john.Courses.Count && x.Courses.Count == john.Courses.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: This is pretty easy to understand. Thank you!